# android: align Button and ToggleButton horizontally in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout

if I try to align the toggle inbetween two buttons within a LinearLayout, I always come up with something where the toggle is slightly misaligned by about 2px to the bottom. I tried a RelativeLayout and also `android:layout_gravity=""center_vertical"`.

Thanx, Huck

Comment: I think this is a bug and you should report a bug

Answer (score 6):

I just added android:layout_gravity=""center_vertical" to both controls and the desaligment dissapears.  although I am using SDK 2.3.3

Answer (score 3):

Like the guy above said : This works perfectly..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button  android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />   

<ToggleButton
android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ToggleButton"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```